# soap address location contains docker service name instead of domain name

Tags: spring-boot, docker, soap, wsdl, traefik

I have a spring boot soap web service which runs in a docker container. The spring boot application is exposed on port 8081 and this is the Spring configuration

```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }


    @Bean
    public XsdSchema userSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("users.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean(name = "user")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema userSchema) {

        DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        definition.setSchema(userSchema);
        definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        definition.setPortTypeName("UserServicePort");
        definition.setTargetNamespace("http://demo.example.com/user");
        return definition;
    }
```

And following is the docker compose file for this application and I have exposed this application through a traefik load balancer

```
version: '3.0'

services:
   hello-app:
     image: hello
     labels:
      - traefik.enable=true   
      - traefik.port=8081
     networks:
      - web 
     deploy:
      replicas: 1

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

And this is the configuration for traefik. It will redirect requests which comes for `http://localhost/mydomain` to `http://hello-app:8081`

```
[entryPoints]
 [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[api]
dashboard = true

[file]
  [backends]
      
    [backends.mydomain]
      [backends.mydomain.servers.server]
      url = "http://hello-app:8081" 
      
    [frontends.mydomain]
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "mydomain"
      [frontends.mydomain.routes.traefik]
      rule = "PathPrefixStrip:/mydomain"  

[docker]
```

My problem is that when I get the WSDL for this URL it contains `http://hello-app:8081/ws` as the soap address location.
[image]

When I create a soap project in SOAP UI using the wsdl `http://localhost/mydomain/ws/user.wsdl`
I get `http://hello-app:8081/ws` as the request address which is incorrect. It should be `http://localhost/mydomain/ws/`
[image]

So how do I configure the soap:address location to be `<soap:address location="http://localhost/mydomain/ws"/>`
in the wsdl.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: I gave the domain in setLocationURI() method. ->

DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
definition.setSchema(userSchema);
definition.setLocationUri("http://mydomain/ws");

Comment: I also think you have to set-> servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(false);